# How do I register a HttpModule in the machine.config for IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, configuration, httpmodule

I'm trying to install a HttpModule on all sites on a server. It is already in the GAC and is working on sites if I individually add the proper configuration to each site's `web.config` file. When I move the configuration into the `machine.config` or the global `web.config`, the module disappears.

Right now, I have the config in the `system.webserver/httpModules` and the `system.web/httpModules` sections in both the 32 bit and 64 bit `machine.config` and global `web.config` - eight places total and none of them are working.

I've installed modules in the `machine.config` on IIS6 before and it is easy. Is there a trick for installing them in IIS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `machine.config` is not responsible for defining the `system.webServer` section. In fact, it defines the section as

```
<section name="system.webServer" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Note the type: `System.Configuration.IgnoreSection`.

The `system.webServer` section is defined in

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config
```

Directly after the `system.webserver` section, there is

```
<location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>

    <modules>
        <!-- add the module here -->
        <add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule, MyAssmebly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdefhijklmnop"/>

    </modules>

    </system.webServer>

</location>
```